# Añadir un array a una celda de dataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tras crear una matriz con los MFCCs de varios audios, quiero añadirlos al dataframe en el que se encuentran el resto de características del audio. Me gustaría **guardar cada columna de la matriz de MFCCs en un array**, y ese array guardarlo en la celda correspondiente del dataframe de las características. ¿se podría hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se si tengo claro el resultado que quieres ¿Cada columna o cada fila? ¿No sería la fila con índice 532 en `mfccs_df` almacenarla en la celda de la columna `mfccs` del dataframe características con el mismo índice (532)?

Comment: No, lo que yo quiero es, por ejemplo, la columna 'mfccs_mean_0', guardarla en una celda de una columna (llamada por ejemplo mfccs1) del otro dataframe (el de 'Nombre del audio', 'Canal vocal'...). Muchas gracias por tu rápida respuesta!!

Comment: Vale, pero ¿cómo asocias cada columna con la celda que le corresponde? ¿Cómo determinas que mfccs_mean_0 va a esa celda y no a otra de la columna? Creo que si agregas dos pequeños ejemplos de cada DataFrame y la salida que esperas para ese ejemplo terminaremos antes. Guardar un array NumPy en la celda es trivial realmente, la clave es lo que comento.

Comment: Para cada audio calculo los mfccs, como salida obtengo una matriz de 13 columnas. Cada columna quiero guardarla en la celda correspondiente del df de las características. Por ejemplo: para el audio 03-01-01-01-01-01-01.wav calculo su mfccs y obtengo una matriz de 13 columnas, la primera columna guardarla en el df de características en la primera celda  debajo de la columna de mfcc_mean_0; la segunda columna de la matriz guardarla en el df principal en la primera celda bajo la columna mfcc_mean_1 y así sucesivamente. Adjunto nueva imagen a la pregunta a ver si se entiende un poco mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que tienes los nombres de cada audio en la primera columna, una forma muy simple de hacer lo que quieres es usar `pandas.Series.apply` sobre la columna 
Nombre del audio. Tienes dos paréntesis alrededor del nombre que no se porqué están ahí, tendremos que eliminarlos.

```
def obtener_mfccs(ruta, res_type, sr, offset, n_mfcc):
    ruta = ruta[1:-1] # para eliminar los paréntesis del nombre
    x, sample_rate = librosa.load(ruta, res_type=res_type, sr=sr, offset=offset)
    mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=x, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=n_mfcc)
    return pd.Series(mfcc for mfcc in mfccs)



num_mfcc = 13
mfccs_cols = [f"mfccs_mean_{n}" for n in range(num_mfcc)]
resultados[mfccs_cols] = resultados["Nombre del audio"].apply(obtener_mfccs,
                                                              res_type='kaser_fast',
                                                              sr=22050*2,
                                                              offset=0.5,
                                                              n_mfcc=num_mfcc)
```

> ```
> >>> resultados["mfccs_mean_5"][0]
> [8.23920823 9.87971604 6.59081934 ... 6.63910554 0.02737212 0.        ]
>
> >>> resultados["mfccs_mean_5"][0].shape
> (30524,)
>
> >>> type(resultados["mfccs_mean_5"][0])
> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
> ```

Comment: Perdona, no vi tu respuesta! Pero efectivamente, esa es la solución. Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y tu rápida respuesta.

Comment: @user132361 Si la respuesta es lo que necesitabas, deberías marcarla como "aceptada" para que pueda ser útil a otros.